# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

As stated [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) about a week or two into the public beta, three candidates will be appointed moderator *pro tempore*.
This is a thread to nominate such candidates.

Nominees should:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

with bonus points for

- Participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Having already shown an interest or ability to promote the community.

Each nomination should be posted in a seperate answer, including a link to the user profile (parent and meta) and links to other activities (e.g., Area 51, blogs or other resources announcing/reviewing the community).

If the nomination is done by a 3rd-party, the nominee should edit the answer and state whether he accepts the nomination, preferably also writing something about them self.
A nomination should be marked community wiki, such that potential new nominees with low reputation may edit the post.

Self nomination is okay and even encouraged. This is a way of saying “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.”

Any nominations posted here should be made CW so that the nominees can themselves edit in their responses. Comments are not the best place for accepts/declines as they may get hidden over time.

Comment: Shucks, I had this question written up :p ([more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181383/when-should-moderator-pro-tempore-nominations-start))

Comment: IMO those who are familiar with [**10k mod**](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) tool on other site and devoted about FAQ post quality and can handle stuff with his knowledge/cleverness Its not important that user can answer every question or capable to answer Mod should be who , who can handle flag and other things.

Comment: @RobertCartaino♦ np.... thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### jmort253

Jumping the gun a bit here, but I'd like to nominate [jmort253](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users/64/jmort253) ([meta](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/64/jmort253)).

He has two pro-tem diamonds already, and I feel his record speaks for itself.

Here's his [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/265671/jmort253); see for yourself!

Answer (score 5):

## Hiroto

[[Profile]](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users/58/hiroto) [[Meta]](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58/hiroto) [[Network]](http://stackexchange.com/users/1878189/hiroto)

I'd really like to nominate myself to be a moderator on Freelancing.SE.

I want to see this site succeed, and I've been active since the second the private beta was announced; mostly in meta (where the vast majority of my activity has been), but also in reviewing, helping new users learn what Stack Exchange is all about, and discussing critical topics for the site (most importantly, the <strike>FAQ</strike> *ahem*, *[Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center)*).

For those of you who like stats, I'm currently in the [top 3 for participation in meta](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/users). However, I'd prefer to be known for quality questions and answers, rather than stats.

I also have ample experience in moderating particularly toxic chatrooms on IRC, so I've seen my share of that end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

## Chris Travers

I am willing to take this on if necessary.  While I have not done much moderation on .se sites yet, I help manage the community resources of [LedgerSMB](http://www.ledgersmb.org) and this includes ensuring that the tones are set for the email lists, that people who step out of that tone are politely warned, and that problem users are eventually banned.  We actually haven't had to ban users yet, and I think that speaks well for our approach.

Answer (score 3):

## Chris W Rea

So far, this site has encountered some issues related to tagging and location where Chris's input has proven to be extremely valuable.

[Chris](http://stackexchange.com/users/30864/chris-w-rea?tab=top) is a moderator on [Personal Finance and Money](http://money.stackexchange.com), which is a site where location-specific issues pop up a lot.  In addition, Personal Finance attracts some of the more subjective, softer, non-technical questions where answering with facts, references, and specific expertise is critical to making sure people find good answers to their questions. Freelancing SE also attracts questions where this style of answering is important.

Chris's experience with Stack Exchange and common sense approach to tackling site issues has thus far proved to be valuable, so I've nominated him as a moderator candidate.

Comment: Good choice; he's already shown himself to be moderator material before, and continues to.

Answer (score 2):

## Luke

I would like to self-nominate myself. I'm a very active user on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) ([User profile](https://superuser.com/users/24010/luke)), and have worked both for companies, agencies, and as a freelancer. I have offered some advice in the limited time I have had on the beta, and know the rules fairly well (i.e. spotting non-constructive questions rather quickly) for the SE network.

I am hoping to dedicate a little more time in a couple weeks as soon as my life slows down a little bit, and I am on the SE many times throughout the day asking/answering/flagging questions.

If nominated, I promise I won't post information against the (eventual) FAQ, and to help out the community be as great as it can be! I will be encouraging other SE members I have befriended as soon as the Public Beta can start, and I know they will put in their years of experience as well to help this site grow